# Bitmap size on disk issue in Android

Tags: android, android-volley, android-sdcard, android-bitmap

In my Application, i need to download the image from server and save it in SDcard. I am using Volley library to download the image from server. Issue in my Application is when i am downloading the image from server it is 30kb and after downloaded checking the size of that image in SDcard was 200kb.

This is my `SavedSDcard()` which is used to save the image in SDcard and returning the ImagePath.

```
public String SavedInSDCard(Bitmap bitmap_in, String id) {

    File dir = new File(ApplicationController.getInstance()
            .getExternalFilesDir("MyApplicationName") + "/Cache");
    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(dir, id);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap_in.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String imgPath = dir + "/" + id;
    return imgPath;
}
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: I don't understand your code. Where is "bitmap_in" used and what is bitmap2? Why do you use compress?

Comment: @maveň Downloaded ImageSize is not same as image Size which is in Server

Comment: @user3208981 debug and test yourself

Answer (score 2):

```
bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

Remove above line from the code.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

`bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);`

You can decrease the value of *100* for reducing the Image Size. put ***70 or 80*** instead of 100.

**Second**

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: by doing this whether it affects image quality?

Comment: If you can send a single  Image URL. So I will let you know the soultion

Comment: Then how will i get same size of the server Image downloaded in SDCard?

Comment: @A M : This is the sample URL "http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20150102074354/pokemon/images/1/16/025Pikachu_OS_anime_10.png"